# Javascript Hide field when one of 6 drop-down options is chosen

Tags: javascript, field, hide

The Admit Type field is a drop-down field on the form, and I am trying to create a function that will hide the School field when a specific Admit Type is chosen.  I would like the school field to show if any of the other 5 Admit Types are selected.

I am newer than new to javascript, apologies if this is hard to look at!

```
//Code to check if Admit Type is 08. Hides School Field
<script>
// set IDs of selectors to use
var admitTypeID = "ctl00_mainContent_ApplicationForm_ApplicationForm_ApplicationFormControl_datatel_admittypeid_datatel_admittypeid"
var SchoolID = "ctl00_mainContent_ApplicationForm_ApplicationForm_ApplicationFormControl_new_school_new_school"
// attach onChange event listener to the fields
var admitType = document.getElementById(admitTypeID);


admitType.addEventListener("change", checkAdmitTypeFunction);

function checkAdmitTypeFunction(){

    if(admitType.value == "0f72309f-a3eb-e511-811c-1292f4bb68c9"){
        document.getElementById(SchoolID).style.visibility="hidden";
    } else if (admitType.value == "0772309f-a3eb-e511-811c-1292f4bb68c9"){
        document.getElementByID(SchoolID).style.visibility="visible";
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Whats the issue you are having with your code?

Comment: I actually fixed my own issue for once!  I needed to change the getElementByID to getElementById.  Thanks!